# python bs4 not finding div

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape https://www.edsurge.com/product-reviews/curriculum-products/math

When I do this :

```
site = 'https://www.edsurge.com/product-reviews/curriculum-products/math'
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(urlopen(site),"html5lib")
print soup
```

I can find the div I am looking for `<div class="browse-main p1">`

However, when I try to find it using:

```
for div in soup.findall('div',class_='browse-main p1'):
        print div
```

I get this error (probably meaning that it can't find the div).

```
for div in soup.findall('div',class_='browse-main p1'):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I also tried using `soup.findall('div')` and it can't find any.
I know I could use selenium, but if it is not necessary, I would rather not. What I find odd is that the div is present when I print soup.

Anyone know what is going on ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `findall` is None, so its uncallable.

Try:

```
for div in soup.findAll('div',class_='browse-main p1'):
```

Comment: To expand on the answer: `soup` implements the `__getattr__` hook (for dynamic attributes resolution) but doesn't properly raise an AttributeError for unknown methods - instead it returns `None`. Since the method is name `findAll` (not `findall`), `soup.findall` actually evals to `None`, which is (of course) not callable, hence the error message.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, I've made your comment into a community answer (below) as it is important information. Feel free to edit it and add some points (if any).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [@bruno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41316/bruno-desthuilliers) in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50294494/python-bs4-not-finding-div#comment87607881_50294690):

`soup` implements the `__getattr__` hook (for dynamic attributes resolution) but doesn't properly raise an `AttributeError` for unknown methods - instead it returns `None`. Since the method is name `findAll` (not `findall`), `soup.findall` actually evals to `None`, which is (of course) not callable, hence the error message.

Also, note that [`findAll()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names) is bs3 syntax. The syntax for bs4 is [`find_all()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all).

So, you should use

```
soup.find_all('div',class_='browse-main p1')
```

and not

```
soup.findall('div',class_='browse-main p1')
```